# Get element by class name from view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I tried to get element inside table by class name from the view

Html file:

```
     <td class="centerText myclassName">Test Value</td>
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void save(FormCollection collection)
    {....}
```

My problem is that in the collection I can got elemeny only by name and to td I can't give attribute name

how can I solve it?

Comment: The big problem you are going to have is that a TD is a pure html element, and is not passed back as part of the FormCollection object. Only input types (text boxes, selects, etc) are passed in as part of the FormCollection. If you want that data, the best way I can think of to do it would be via an AJAX call where you have full control, and use javascript to place the td value into the data object for transmission to the server. Then you can give it any name you want.

Comment: guildsbounty,got it,thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that your table is wrapped in a `<form>` tag, a quick way to achieve this would be to use hidden inputs:

```
<td class="centerText myclassName">
    <input type="hidden" name="someName" value="Test Value" />
    Test Value
</td>
```

And then just fetch the value in your controller, as you would with any other form post.

If this doesn't meet your requirements, then your best bet is doing as @guildsbounty suggests.